# How do I extrude only a small portion of a face?

Tags: faces, extrude

I have a cylinder and I want to extrude only a small portion of one of its faces inwards. How would I do this?

Comment: You don't, a face is the smallest addressable visible unit in mesh modelling. If you want to manipulate only a part of it you have to subdivide it into smaller faces.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you want the extrude a small portion of the plan(a).
plan(a) is 1m*1m . We will extrude 0.5m*0.5m know as plan(b):

Select plan(a),
(1)use the extrude fonction but do not extrude yet

(2)change to scale fonction and now you can extrude. You have now the plan(b) inside the plan(a). With both plan perfectily aligned.

(3)Now you can extrude plan(b)

In the picture attached the you can see the face and profile view so it will be more clear.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Knife on the selected face then extrude:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I know it sounds obvious but: Extrude inwards. Select the face and the shortcut is `I` instead of `E`.

Funny, but I can't find the command reference at the moment! Should be in the Blender Docs somewhere.

Comment: I is the shortcut for "inset"

Comment: Selecting face and insetting it with I shortcut vs. selecting face, extruding with E shortcut and scaling it down will give the same result in this case